# You don’t have permission to save the file “988BF072-A4B9-4ABE-9FB8-2F3A8EBC2E2C” in the folder “CoreSimulator”

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

This folder exists.

I've tried moving it to the trash (it reappears and then this message pops up).

I've reset all permission to all enclosed folders to R+W.

I've repaired permissions on my drive.

Plugging in a real phone works fine (probably not relevant).
[image]
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you ran something as root. Perform `grep -R "988BF072-A4B9-4ABE-9FB8-2F3A8EBC2E2C” ~/`, and then fix the permissions.

Comment: Thanks, but the permissions for that folder and all enclosed folders are R+W (see image I attached). I also included a second image for another error that comes up. Maybe they are related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the actual folder for the log file didn't exist.

When looking in Console.app, filtering on CoreSimulator, I saw this:

> 3/15/15 9:50:52.840 AM iOS Simulator[7291]: Error opening
>   /Users//Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/iOS Simulator.log

When I went to the Logs directory, CoreSimulator wasn't there, so I:

```
sudo mkdir CoreSimulator
sudo chown <user>:staff CoreSimulator
touch CoreSimulator/iOS\ Simulator.log
```

Comment: Yeah, so apparently your ~/Library/Logs directory has incorrect ownership or permissions.  You should fix that and also fix the ownership and permissions on the CoreSimulator directory that you created as part of your answer as well.

Answer (score 18):

Just finished solving this problem. I think the main issue is that you are looking in the wrong place. These are the steps I took:

1. Make hidden folders visible by going to terminal and executing these two commands:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

   killall Finder
   ```
2. Go to /Users/myUsername/Library now it should be visible ( instead of myUsername  you should have yours)
3. The Logs folder has no access permission, so change it. In case you can't do it manually, go to 3b.

   3b. Open terminal. Write this command

   ```
   sudo chmod 777 ~/Library/Logs
   ```
4. Be happy

P.S. In case you don't want to see hidden folder and files anymore,
execute this two lines in terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE

killall Finder
```

Answer (score 6):

So your permissions are invalid.  You should look in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator and check what the ownership and permissions are set to and fix them.

If that doesn't work, update your question with explanation of what you tried and show the current ownership and permissions on the relevant paths.

Comment: I've added images showing the permissions and errors message. I've tried different targets as well. There is a separate error that comes up that may be the culprit (image attached).

Comment: Your finder window is actually covering the ownership in your screenshot.  Additionally, you're looking at the wrong path.  I'm sorry for the err on my part.  Look at ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

run this command in terminal before code building.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue, you just need to go to the logs in your library and change permissions to read and writes.

Answer (score 0):

Manually changing the permissions of `/private/var/tmp/` to allow writes by everyone fixed this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).