# Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-tvOS Main.storyboard

Tags: xcode, tvos

I am trying to build a brand new tvOS project. All I have done at this point is "New Project". Selected all the default settings. When I try to run, I keep getting the following two errors:

1) Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-tvOS Main.storyboard

2) Failed to launch IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool via CoreSimulator spawn Assets.xcassets

I am using the base Apple TV simulator.

Here is what I tried:

1) Uninstalled and re-installed XCode straight from the app store
2) Made sure my computer was all up to date
3) Build Clean, Exit XCode, Restart XCode, Run

I was able to resolve the second issue (partly) by removing Assets.xcassets from the Copy Bundle Resources steps as was suggested in another post but when I put it back in, the error comes back. I can't get rid of the first error.

With XCode 10.1 straight from the app store on Mac OS X 10.14.3 all up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I had given up on this one but finally lucked out and found the issue. The fix for this [You don’t have permission to save the file “988BF072-A4B9-4ABE-9FB8-2F3A8EBC2E2C” in the folder “CoreSimulator”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055007/you-don-t-have-permission-to-save-the-file-988bf072-a4b9-4abe-9fb8-2f3a8ebc2e2c) resolved my issue.

Comment: Thanks. sudo chmod 777 ~/Library/Logs worked for me.